# Switch и двойное условие? Массив и его заполнение?

Tags: java

1) Как сделать в обычном примере двойное условие в switch? Перепробовал всё что можно.

В этом примере ругается компилятор.

```
public class Ivan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5, b = 10;

        switch(a, b){
            case 5:
            case 10:
                System.out.println("Правильно");
                break;
            case 6:
            case 11:
                System.out.println("Неправильно");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Потеря потерь");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Можно ли в массив с размером 10 элементов через цикл заполнить в него значения в каждый элемент? Если да, то как?

3)Можно ли сделать так, чтобы массив содержал и строки и целые числа и дробные допустим. Если да, то как?

```
Какой-нибудь_общий_тип array[] = {1, "Hello", 12.5};
```

Заранее благодарю вас добрые люди!

Comment: переписал ответ

Comment: все понятно расписал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос: Да, можно.

```
switch(a) { 
            case 1: //если а = 1
                switch(b) { 
                    case 1: 
                         System.out.println("1");
                         break; 
                }
                break;
            case 2: если a = 2
                switch(b) { 
                    case 1: 
                         System.out.println("1");
                         break; 
                }   
        }
```

Но данный оператор для этого не используется. Для этого есть `if`.

Ответ на второй вопрос: Да, можно.

```
int a = 0;
for(int i; i < mass.length; i++) { 
      mass[i] = a++;  
}
```

Ответ на трети вопрос: Да, можно. Для этого следует написать:

```
Object mass[] = {1, "4", new NewClass(){}, 1.28}; //где NewClass - воображаемый
```

анонимный класс, объявляемый с помощью интерфейса (просто пример)

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажите как разные значения записать в массив? А не только одно :)

Comment: А почему такая странная конструкция у switch?

Comment: одно из причин - он для этого не используется

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван изменил ответ